# Radio inputs in two separate shadow doms not respecting name attribute

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom

I am using a [MDC Radio Element](https://material.io/components/web/catalog/input-controls/radio-buttons/) so I thought I would wrap it up in a nice little `<mdc-radio name="the-name" value="the-value"></mdc-radio>`.

Everything was going well, but then I realized when I use it multiple times w/ the same `name` attribute...

```
<mdc-radio name="the-name" value="the-value-1"></mdc-radio>
<mdc-radio name="the-name" value="the-value-2"></mdc-radio>
```

.. it does not toggle the other selected `mdc-radio` with the same name. I assume it is because the radios are in two separate shadow dom containers. Is this correct? is there a way around this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

dang... that was a dumb question. I assumed using Shadow DOM was required for Custom Elements, but it isn't. Just appending the MDC Radio markup to `this` inside of the constructor for a `HTMLElement` did the trick